# Cancellation in topological product

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I was wondering whether $M\times \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $N\times \mathbb{R}$ implies $M$ is homeomorphic to $N$, where let us say $M,N$ are smooth manifolds. (They are certainly homotopy equivalent.) More generally what if $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by some other manifold say $\Sigma$? Any possible approach/idea?

Comment: Just an idea, but maybe try projecting onto the first components of each space. Let $f:M \times R \rightarrow N \times R$ be a homeomorphism, then $ \pi_{1} \circ f$ is certainly a continuous map $M \rightarrow N $. You'd just have to prove it's bijective.

Comment: @TheBluegrassMathematician: You probably mean $\pi_1 \circ f \circ \iota$, where $\iota : M \to M \times \Bbb{R}$, e.g. $\iota(x)=(x,0)$. The problem is that this map has no reason to be bijective (it seems)

Comment: This is one of my favorite "surprisingly deep with a surprising answer" questions in topology.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is no.

Let $X$ be the [Whitehead manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold) which is a contractible three-dimensional manifold. Despite the fact that $X$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, $X\times\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4 = \mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}$.

Note, there is a [similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/125935/21564) on MathOverflow that may be of interest.

Comment: Is there any mild condition that can be imposed on $M,N$ so that the answer is affermative?

Comment: I am not aware of such a condition.