# Characterize all topological spaces with a certain cancellation rule

Tags: general-topology

It is possible to determine all topological spaces $(X,\tau)$ such that, for all $A,B\subseteq X$ that satisfied $A\times [0,1]\sim B\times [0,1]$, then $A\sim B$?

That is, to characterize all topological spaces where the cancellation rule are valid.

Comment: What does the symbol $\sim$ mean? Also, what do you mean by "determine"? Most likely, the class of topological spaces you will get is not even a set.

Comment: $\sim$ is used for homeomorphic spaces. Why this class is bot a set?

Comment: @studiosus: It isn’t a set, since it includes all discrete spaces and all indiscrete spaces. That’s already two spaces for each cardinal greater than $1$.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057793/cancellation-in-topological-product)