# Cartesian product of connected spaces with a common factor

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose $U$, $V$ and $W$ are connected topological spaces. Is it possible for $U \times V$ and $U \times W$ to be homeomorphic but for $V$ and $W$ not to be? It seems like it should not always be true but I am unable to find a counterexample.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396608/does-x-times-s1-cong-y-times-s1-imply-that-x-times-mathbb-r-cong-y-times-ma/410699#410699, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057793/cancellation-in-topological-product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$, $V$, and $W$ all have the indiscrete topology with $0<|V|<|W|\leq |U|$ and $|U|$ infinite.  Then $U\times V$ and $U\times W$ both have the indiscrete topology and have cardinality $|U|$, and so they are homeomorphic.  But $V$ and $W$ have different cardinality and so are not homeomorphic.

For another example, let $U=V=[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ and $W=[0,1]$.  Then $U\times V\cong U\times W\cong [0,1]^\mathbb{N}$, but $V\not\cong W$.  You can find many similar examples using infinite products like this.

For some further discussion and some more surprising examples, see [this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26385/when-factors-may-be-cancelled-in-homeomorphic-products).

Comment: The example I find most amusing is the one of ${\mathbb Q}^2\cong {\mathbb Q}\times \{0\}$. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26001/are-the-rationals-homeomorphic-to-any-power-of-the-rationals